# How do i end a loop using a different character like "x" or so

Tags: java

I have this code which is a minigame, you type a number and if is divisible by 5 you get a "Fizz" / if divisible by 3 you get a "Buzz" / and if divisible by both, you get a "FizzBuzz".

Now, i need help to end the "while(true)" loop, peacefully with a mesage like... "goodbye" whenever you enter the letter "X".

I would apreciate if you can add the aswer to the full code and a little explain of the code.

```
public class CLass {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
        System.out.print("number:  ");

        number = scan.nextInt();

                if (number % 5 == 0 && number % 3 == 0)
                    System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
                else if (number % 5 == 0)
                    System.out.println("Fizz");
                else if (number % 3 == 0)
                    System.out.println("Buzz");
                else
                    System.out.println(number);
   }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you mean when somebody types a different letter and presses enter? It looks like that will end your loop in the current form.

Comment: yes it did end, but it ends "brutally" with an error like: 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
And i want to make it say : "goodbye"

Comment: Right now you're using "nextInt" instead you should use "next" or "nextLine" that returns a string. You could also "handle the exception".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input;
do {
    input = scan.next();
    if(!Objects.equals(input, "x")){
       System.out.println("your input is: " + input);
       ...
    }
} while(!Objects.equals(input, "x"));
System.out.println("Goodbye");
```

And if you need to convert the string into `int`, take a look on some solutions here:

[How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Comment: i have no ideea how to implement that =))) 
Btw... i m new to this, and that code was an exercice i found on Youtube and i wanted to upgrade it like make a loop and end it with X and a line that says "Goodbye"

Comment: What do you expect that your loop will do? (I added the print that you want to my code)

Comment: The code provided is very basic! If you can't understand I suggest you go through some online tutorials to cover the basics first! @omerblechman